# Spark: Why is createGlobalTempView() Method Not Available in spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

In spark-shell, the 2 methods createGlobalTempView() and createOrReplaceGlobalTempView() are not available for datasets; can anyone tell me this would be the case. Obviously even in spark-shell, we can create new sessions as in spark.newSession.  So, why are these 2 methods not available?  The code below shows you what I mean:

```
scala> spark.range(100).create
createOrReplaceTempView   createTempView

scala> spark.range(100).create
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reateGlobalTempView` is available in since Spark 2.1 and there is no difference between `spark-shell` and other context. If you cannot **call** the method you probably use Spark 2.0. Otherwise it is just a completion fluke:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_141)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> spark.range(100).createGlobalTempView("foo")

scala>
```